# How to implement LIKE% with single quote in SQL Server search from C# textbox.Text value?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, textbox

MY SQL Server's SELECT statement has the current WHERE clause in my C#:

```
strQuery4_main += " WHERE ([Description] LIKE ";
strQuery4_main += "'" + txtbox_ReportBy_start.Text + "%" + "'";
strQuery4_main += " ) ";
```

If I input a keyword

**nature**

in my txtbox_ReportBy_start textbox,
the query will search anything starts with the name 'nature', which is fine.

But if I search the keyaord

**nature's path**

then the error message will occur saying

> Incorrect syntax near '-'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character
>   string 'AS [ ]'.

I understand I should use two single quotes to replace one single quote, but how should that work in the textbox value?

Comment: Are you aware that this is highly open to SQL injection attacks?

Comment: SQL injection is the first thing that came to my mind seeing this.

Comment: ' I don't know what you guys are talking about --

Comment: Obligatory:  http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Parameters with your query. Concatenated query would also be prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
strQuery4_main += " WHERE ([Description] LIKE @pDescription";
```

Later with your command object do:

```
yourCommandObject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDescription", 
                                           txtbox_ReportBy_start.Text +"%");
```

You may see: [Parameterizing Your SQL Queries: The RIGHT Way To Query A Database](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/).

Currently you are getting the error because your single quote in the input is not escaped. You can escape the single quote using another single quote. But you should always consider using parameters with your query.